# How to fix POST 404 error using node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm I'm stuck in post request while I'm developing upload images in **quill editor**. 
I have no idea what I have to do to fix this issue.
When I try to send data using post request, then 404 error occur.

[image]

**routes/img.js** - **UPDATED**

```
var ImageFile = require('../models/imageFiles');

var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'img/') // Set directory
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.name) // Set file name
    }
});

var img = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/upload', img.single('imgfile'), (req, res, next) => {
    var imageFile = new ImageFile({
        name: req.body.name,
        type: req.body.type,
        size: req.body.size,
        content: req.body.content
    });

    imageFile.save((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occured',
                error: err
            });
        }
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'User created',
            obj: result
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var appRoutes = require('./routes/app');
var userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
var imgRoutes = require('./routes/img');
var app = express();

// Start
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../awesome-drill/dist')));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-Width, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

app.use('/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/img', imgRoutes);
app.use('/', appRoutes);
app.use(express.static('routes'));

// It's for routing SPA
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../awesome-drill/dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

**frontside service (angular4)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class FileService {
  public userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  imgUpload(obj) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(obj);
    const headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    return this.http.post('img/upload', body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
}
```

Thanks to you, I found my mistake and I added it. However, 404 error still occur.

It's my folder structure.
[image]

Comment: Please update your answer to include the frontend code that's actually posting to your route. A 404 means not found so you can also remove the mongoose model code since it has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: It means that you are sending data to the wrong URI or that the URI you think you defined on the back-end does not actually exist. 404 means "not found", and since your code is not emitting that error explicitly for a "not found result" then the only other place is because of the incorrect URL.,

Comment: your app.js should have a regular 404 `middleware` function, at Least I remember the initial express.js setup used to add it. Is it at least hitting your controller? or do you have another `middleware` function that may be throwing this?

Comment: @Soviut I updated my post, please check it out

Comment: @NeilLunn, Yeah, I agree with you. But, I have no idea what I did wrong. Can you give some advice?

Comment: @DavidEspino I updated my post, Please check it out :)

Comment: Where are you exporting `router` in `routes/img.js`? It's not shown in your question or is actually missing completely

Comment: @NeilLunn is right... you need `module.exports = router; ` at the end of your controller :/

Comment: @DavidEspino I fixed it but 404 error still occur

Comment: @NeilLunn I know it was my mistake, so I fixed it, but still it happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't exporting your router. Add the following to the end of your `routes/img.js` file.

```
module.exports = router;
```

The way you have it now, there is no default export, so when you `require('./routes/img')` you're importing nothing. If you were to `console.log(imgRoutes)` in `app.js` it would probably return `undefined`.

Comment: I thought I could have solved this issue, but it still make 404 error...

Comment: The there's another reason your route doesn't exist. Either set a bunch of `console.log()` to see if your module is importing correctly, or tep through each part of the code using `debugger;` https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html