# POST request working on localhost, but cannot POST to AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I can't solve my problem. I stuck in this issue for a long time, so now I'm asking you.
Here, this was [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248240/how-to-fix-post-404-error-using-node-js/46248742?noredirect=1#comment79497718_46248742) before I posted.

I made a mistake that I didn't export module at that time.
Now, I tested in localhost, it works well.

[image]

However, if I test with postman, it doesn't work at all like bellow

[image]

If you guys have this experience and resolved, then please give me some tips to resolve this issue.

It's my app.js, routes/imgFiles.js and models/imgFiles.js

---

### app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../awesome-drill/dist')));

app.use(logger('dev'));

const appRoutes = require('./routes/app');
const imgRoutes = require('./routes/imgFiles');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

app.use(imgRoutes);
app.use(userRoutes);
app.use(appRoutes);

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-Width, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
});

app.use(express.static('routes'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../awesome-drill/dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

---

### models/imgFiles.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var ImageFile = require('../models/imageFiles');

var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '../img/') // Set directory
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.name) // Set file name
    }
});
var img = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/uploadFiles',img.single('imgfile'), (req, res) => {
    var imageFile = new ImageFile({
        imgName: req.body.imgName,
        imgType: req.body.imgType,
        imgSize: req.body.imgSize,
        imgContent: req.body.imgContent
    });

    imageFile.save((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occured',
                error: err
            });
        }
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Img saved',
            obj: result
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

### models/imgFiles.js

```
var {mongoose} = require('../db/mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    imgName: {
        type: String,
    },

    imgType: {
        type: String,
    },

    imgSize: {
        type: Number,
    },

    imgContent: {
        type: String,
    },
});

schema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('ImageFile', schema);
```

Comment: How did you deploy it ? On an EC2 instance ? Does the app starts fine on your AWS machine ? It could be tons of issues, from firewall to missing dependencies, to mongodb connection failures...

Comment: @FrançoisP. I deployed to on EC2. Can you give me some tips? I have no idea what I have to do :(

Comment: @FrançoisP. It's on Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: So, did you ssh to your EC2 instance, pull your code and ran it ? In that case does it run fine ?

Comment: It could be many thing, it could be your security group blocking the port, it could be dependency missing etc. What have you done so far on your EC2 instance ?

Comment: Yeah it was totally fine. Actually, some of POST request is fine before I made such as sign in and sign out. However, This time, when I try to add POST request api, this error occurred. I set totally same with other POST request APIs, but it doesn't work and 404 error occur.

Comment: can you wrap the content of your route in a `try { } catch(e) { console.log(e) }` statement and see if it logs any error

Comment: It works well on localhost. I'm using pm2. Is it possible to cause this issue?